# Javascript immutability and local array

Tags: javascript, arrays, immutability

UPDATE: I now understand that in the code below I am mutating the `aggregateData` array as I iterate through `pagedData`.

1. I'd like to know how I could do this without mutation?
2. And in general how much concern there might be when mutating a locally defined array (like I did in my example) when trying to respect immutability as much as possible in a codebase? Since the array is defined locally I wonder how mutating the array could really have any negative impact?

```
const pagedData = [
  {data: ["val1", "val2"], nextPage: 2},
  {data: ["val3", "val4"], nextPage: 3},
  {data: ["val5", "val6"]}
];

const aggregator = () => {
  let aggregateData = [];
  let hasNextPage;
  let page = 1;

  do {
    const { data, nextPage } = pagedData[page - 1];
    aggregateData = [...aggregateData, ...data];
    page = nextPage;
    hasNextPage = nextPage;
  } while (hasNextPage);

  return aggregateData;
}

console.log(aggregator());

/* output: ["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4", "val5", "val6"] */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immutability helps reduce hard to catch bugs sometimes, but that may not always be required or be the ideal case.

**What is Immutability ?**

Not changing the value refers to immutability. In Javascript, [array and objects are mutable](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj0lOGj9bXxAhVylOYKHcALB3YQFjAEegQIChAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FGlossary%2FMutable&usg=AOvVaw3_NmzsLVrLd6dG3pX7uqyX).

Examples of immutability:

```
let arr = ['John', 'Alice'];

// Adding element is mutating
arr.push('Oliver');

// Updating data is mutating
arr[1] = 'Lily'
```

Lot of other functions can mutate this array. More [here](https://dzone.com/articles/immutability-in-javascriptwhy-and-when-should-you)

- copyWithin
- fill
- pop
- push
- reverse
- shift
- sort
- splice
- unshift

Also, note that defining an array or object as a `const` does not guarantee immutability.
For example:

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'foo'
}
// update name
obj.name = 'bar';

console.log(obj);
```

```js
const arr = ['foo'];

// push new item
arr.push('bar');

console.log(arr);
```

Now to answer your question. when can spread operator mutate and when does is not ?

If we have this array, whenever any data in this array mutates, then it loses immutability.

```js
let arr = ['Obito', 'Sasuke'];
let sameReferenceArray = arr;

console.log(arr === sameReferenceArray);

// here the original array did not mutate 
let newArray = [...arr, 'Madara'];
console.log(arr === sameReferenceArray);

// but here it did mutate as the new array is assigned back to arr
arr = [...arr, 'Madara'];
console.log(arr === sameReferenceArray);
```

There are more examples of what methods mutate and what don't and you'll learn them over time.

**Edit**
**How Mutation can have negative impact ?**

```js
// simple example demostrating negative impact of mutataion
const obj = { name: "foo" };
const arr = [obj, obj]

console.log(arr);

// Mutating first element
arr[0].name = "bar";

console.log("Contents after mutation", arr);
```

As you can see, we ended up updating both objects even though we update the one at index 0.
Now I'll spread and mutate:

```js
const obj = { name: "foo" };
const arr = [{...obj}, {...obj}]

console.log(arr);

// Mutating first element
arr[0].name = "bar";

console.log("Contents after mutation", arr);
```

Only the intended element is mutated now.

---

There is a lot more to this. In general, Immutability shouldn't be a very big concern if you've started out to learn. But knowing it certainly helps.

For example in `React` state should not be mutated ([reason](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjdtfOq2rfxAhVfwjgGHW9NCl8QFjACegQIBRAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F37755997%2Fwhy-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really&usg=AOvVaw17KZDKFDkuf11-ZJa03Z0X))

And at last, regarding how to update `aggregatedData'.

```
const aggregator = () => {
  let aggregateData = [];
  let hasNextPage;
  let page = 1;

  do {
    const { data, nextPage } = pagedData[page - 1];
    aggregateData = [...aggregateData, ...data];
    page = nextPage;
    hasNextPage = nextPage;
  } while (hasNextPage);

  return aggregateData;
}
```

Since you're prepending data to an array you'll end up mutating it anyway. You can do `spread` or `push` or whatever. This all is fine since the array is locally created inside the functions and returned.

Example, where it might be an issue:

```
const aggregator = (aggregateData) => {
  for (const i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    aggregateData = [...aggregateData, i];

  return aggregateData;
}

const example = () => {
  let arr = [];
  let data = aggregator(arr);
  // if this array is passed to couple other functions too and mutated then it will get hard to track. This is where the issue can occur

}

example();
```

Comment: Everything you say makes sense and also lead me to further clarify my question. How can I still credit your response even though I would now like additional information?

Comment: Ask me what you require. I'd articulate it. We've reached this far...let's take an extra mile.

Comment: I'd like to know how I could update the aggregateData array in the above example without mutation?

And in general how much concern there might be when mutating a locally defined array (like I did in my example) when trying to respect immutability as much as possible in a codebase? Since the array is defined locally I wonder how mutating the array could really have any negative impact?